# Using Sublime 2 for Haskell Development?

Tags: haskell, ghc, sublimetext, sublimetext2

What is the current status of Sublime 2 integration for Haskell? I see two possible packages so far. A plugin for code highlighting and a REPL plugin.

Is there an intelli-sense plugin for Haskell? 
Maybe integration with Hackage as well?

Thanks.

Comment: I would be very interested in the answer to this question, since I use Sublime Text 2 for most of my development.

Comment: Interested as well. Although the normal word completition is so far enough for me.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/holmak/sublime-text-haskell apparently enhances completion and lists and highlights errors.

Comment: It moved to https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell and will soon support inserting type signatures via ghc-mod as well.

Comment: Just an update on this. I have decided to use emacs with the haskell-mode plugin. It is terrific. Linting, haddock, hoogle, ghci all built in. screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10021156/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-19%20at%202.33.27%20PM.png

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[SublimeHaskell plugin](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell) is the modern choice for Haskell development with SublimeText. It is well maintained and has plenty of useful features.

Other quite useful plugins:

- [Shell Turtlestein](https://github.com/misfo/Shell-Turtlestein), which allows you to quickly type in shell commands under a single keystroke from inside the editor.
- [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), which allows you to run GHCi from inside the editor. Though without support for `cabal repl` yet.
- [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements), which I primarily use to rename/move files without touching the mouse. With it you can hit `Ctrl/Cmd + P` and type "rename" or "move" to enter the dialogue.

Answer (score 7):

I use Sublime exclusively at the moment and while it's not all that special out of the box, installing sublime-text-haskell as Cubic suggested makes it a little better (it will compile and highlight errors when you save a file and apparently enhances the auto-completion).

I've experimented with writing my own plugins but the reality is that a lot of really cool possibilities are made difficult to implement because the API is actually kind of restricting (there's no way to add extra information like type signatures to auto-complete options for example).

It seems that the dev(s) are working on adding some requested API features, but until then, sublime-text-haskell is probably the best Haskell plugin.